# ios7 email signature underlines address

Tags: ios, email, electronic-signature

I've created a signature for a client, who came back to me saying that their office address shows underlined and in blue on iPhone 5. The address is a simple paragraph - no anchor etc. Is there a way to re-enforce is to display as standard text?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but from my experience iOS parses all email addresses and makes them links. If your client doesn't mind you could format the email to contain spaces then the OS wouldn't recognize it as an email and should leave it as text. (name @ domain.com). iOS sees this functionality as a feature. It allows users to find and use emails quickly, instead of having to copy and paste the address into the mail app.

IOS also provides this automated linking for locations so they can be opened in a map application.

Here's a nice post on how to work around this issue: https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices

Comment: But that's not email address - it's the location / office address